SharePoint Framework on SharePoint Server 2019
Which node and which gulp, yo and so on I should install before developing SharePoint Framework on SharePoint 2019 server.
I tried node 11.15. and now I'm try to fight with node 12.22.12 and I can't open:
yo @microsoft/sharepoint

It is showing me:

Please help me.

Try installing below versions for SPFx development on SharePoint Server 2019:

Node.js: v8.17.0
gulp-cli: v2.3.0
yo: v2.0.6

Check below Microsoft official documentations and references for more information:

Set up your SharePoint Framework development environment
SharePoint Framework development tools and libraries compatibility
SharePoint Framework development with SharePoint Server 2019 and Subscription Edition
SharePoint 2019 On Premise SPFx dev setup. which tools versions to serve helloworld?


A couple of things to add to Ganesh's answer.
SharePoint Server 2019 supports the SharePoint Framework v1.4.1, so you need to take that into account when installing the Yeoman SharePoint generator.
Also, in addition to the resources Ganesh linked, I would highly recommend this resource: Definitive guide for developers: SharePoint Framework for SharePoint Server 2019. It's very detailed and covers everything you'll need to know when setting up your development environment.
